# Waiting for a second process to complete before my application continues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

This is my code for executing a **console** application from within my **Visual C++ MFC** application:

```
bool CGoogleAuthandSync::ExecuteProgram(CString strCommand, DWORD &rExitCode)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO         startupInfo = { 0 };
    int                 nStrBuffer;
    BOOL                bProcessResult, bExitCodeProcess;
    bool                bOK = false;
    CWaitCursor         wait;

    rExitCode = -1;

    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    nStrBuffer = strCommand.GetLength() + 50;

    bProcessResult = CreateProcess(NULL, strCommand.GetBuffer(nStrBuffer),
        NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
        NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    strCommand.ReleaseBuffer();

    if (!bProcessResult)
    {
        // CreateProcess() failed
        // Get the error from the system
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

        // Display the error
        CString strError = (LPTSTR)lpMsgBuf;
        TRACE(_T("Authenticate failed at CreateProcess()\nCommand=%s\nMessage=%s\n\n"), strCommand, strError);

        // Free resources created by the system
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

        // We failed.
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Successfully created the process.  Wait for it to finish.
        //WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
        // AJT v14.0.3

        DWORD WaitResult;
        do
        {
            WaitResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,
                // only 1 wait object
                &processInformation.hProcess, // worker thread
                FALSE,   // stop if any
                INFINITE,  // no timeout
                QS_ALLINPUT);
            if (WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
            {
                // Handle windows message
                MSG Msg;
                while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, (UINT)-1, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    TRACE3("%d %d %d\n", Msg.message, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
                    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
                }
            }
        } while (WaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
        //} while (WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1);
        ASSERT(WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0);

        // Get the exit code.
        bExitCodeProcess = GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &rExitCode);

        // Close the handles.
        CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);

        if (!bExitCodeProcess)
        {
            // Could not get exit code.
            TRACE(_T("Executed command but couldn't get exit code.\nCommand=%s\n"), strCommand);
            return false;
        }

    //  if (rExitCode == 0) // We should have returned a value
        //  return false;

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

The calling code does this:

```
bool CGoogleAuthandSync::AddEventsToCalendarXML(CString strXML)
{
    CString strCommand = BuildCommandLine(_T("addtocalendarxml"), strXML);
    DWORD   dwExitCode;

    if (ExecuteProgram(strCommand, dwExitCode))
    {
        if (dwExitCode == 3)
            return true;
        else
        {
            CString strError;

            strError.Format(IDS_TPL_GOOGLE_UPDATE_FAILED, g_strResultDesc[dwExitCode]);
            AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, the main dialogue ( popup window in my application ), that executes a **save** mechanism to write some data to the computer before running the external utility:

```
bool bSyncToGoogle = false;
if (CGoogleCalendarSettingsDlg::GetSyncToGooglePrompt())
{
    if (AfxMessageBox(IDS_STR_SYNC_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_PROMPT, MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
        ExportToGoogleCalendar();
}
else if (CGoogleCalendarSettingsDlg::GetSyncToGoogle())
    ExportToGoogleCalendar();

SetModified(false);
```

So, we have the popup editor ( a dialogue ) in my application.

- The User clicks **Save**.
- It creates some data files.
- It **exports** to Google Calendar.
- Then it sets the **modified** flag as **false**.

Now, I thought I had written this in such a way that the main window would wait until my utility has finished before it continues.

But what I am finding with some users is that they can click save, and then, really quickly, click the X in the top right of the editor. They are able to do this **before** the sync has completed. So it thinks it is still modified.

If they wait a few seconds before clicking the X in the top right then it closes correctly and it considers that the document is no longer modified.

So I have some kind of race issue I guess. But why? Why isn't my application waiting until the sync to Google has completed and it set the modified flag to false before I we allow the user to even consider closing the editor?

Confused.

Comment: I think you do not need the `while (PeekMessage(` loop, as you still use the INFINITE for the Wait command. Get rid of this loop. If you really want to process the GUI messages you need to use the wait command with a timeout, but the dialog must have a synchronised variable that you would check if it is OK to close. The `ExecuteProgram()`  will control this variable

Comment: Try disabling the window before the loop, and enable the window at the end. This way your window doesn't freeze while the thread is working.

Comment: @cha I added the synchronised variable. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Pass the process path as parameter.

```
BOOL exeWait( char* file ) const
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,               // No module name (use command line). 
                    file,               // Command line. 
                    NULL,               // Process handle not inheritable. 
                    NULL,               // Thread handle not inheritable. 
                    FALSE,              // Set handle inheritance to FALSE. 
                    0,                  // No creation flags. 
                    NULL,               // Use parent's environment block. 
                    NULL,               // Use parent's starting directory. 
                    &si,                // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
                    &pi )               // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
                        ) 
    {
            return FALSE;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return TRUE;
}
```